# Styled Components doesn't apply any style on page load

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled Component on a page of my app. Code is really straightforward:

```
// styled component
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledOrdersPage = styled.div`
  background-color: red;

`
export default StyledOrdersPage
```

and here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StyledOrdersPage from './index.styled.js'

class OrdersPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledOrdersPage>
        <p>Simple component</p>
      </StyledOrdersPage>
    );
  }
}

export default OrdersPage;
```

Problem is, I have absolutely no styling on my page whatsoever.

Now, this page can be accessed by using the `/order` route of my app. If I navigate to homepage (`/`), and then to my order page, styling is applied. But if I reload the order page, all styling is gone.

Is this related to styled-components ? Or is this just some weird routing behavior ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This looks like an issue with react-router, you might want to add your routes and config for them.

Comment: try to make the styled components in same component, to check if its related to styled component or not. also remove the p tag for the check simplicity

Comment: Hmm, you are styling `div` but dont have any `div`s in your component, could that be the issue?

Comment: I've been using styled-component from a long time in all my projects and never had that issue. I had an issue with hot reload but i I've solved with the appropriate Babel plugin